# How to increase the table row height for furigana(ruby) in XeLaTeX?

Tags: tables, xetex, cjk

The **ruby** package provides phonetic guide (really, it's possible to use in any language), however, if to use ruby inside the table, the row height will not increased for ruby:
[image: Ruby inside table]

I also used the **bigstrut** package, it wasn't help. 
Is it possible to increase the row height for ruby?

The MWE is

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}      
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{MS PMincho}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
\newfontfamily\russianfont{Calibri}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{bigstrut}

\usepackage{ruby}
\renewcommand{\rubysep}{-0.1ex}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|m{25mm}|m{57mm}|} \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Институт/Руководящая должность} \bigstrut \\ \hline
\ruby{国}{くに}/\ruby{首長}{しゅちょう} & \emph{страна}/\emph{премьер-министр} \bigstrut \\ \hline
\ruby{都道府県}{とどうふけん}/\ruby{知事}{ちじ} & \emph{префектура}/\emph{губернатор} \bigstrut \\ \hline
\ruby{市}{し}/\ruby{市長}{しちょう} & \emph{город}/\emph{мэр} \bigstrut \\ \hline
\ruby{町}{まち}/\ruby{町長}{ちょうちょう} & \emph{район}/\emph{глава района} \bigstrut \\ \hline
\ruby{村}{むら}/\ruby{村長}{そんちょう} & \emph{деревня}/\emph{староста} \bigstrut \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

You will not see the "Bad box" warning in this MWE, however, I saw it in my source document.

Comment: check the `array` package documentation for `\extrarowheight`.  i think this might help (but i'm not able to check the documentation myself just now to be sure).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Barbara Beeton pointed out, the `array` package provides the parameter (lenght) `\extrarowheight` which increases (or decreases if you set a negative value) the height of rows in a `tabular` or `array` environment.

In your case, adding `5pt` to this lenght should be enough. That means adding the line

```
\setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
```

to your document. Also the package `bigstrut` isn't required.

If you rewrite your MWE as

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}      
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{MS PMincho}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
\newfontfamily\russianfont{Calibri}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{ruby}
\renewcommand{\rubysep}{-0.1ex}
\setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}    

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|m{25mm}|m{57mm}|} \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Институт/Руководящая должность} \\ \hline
\ruby{国}{くに}/\ruby{首長}{しゅちょう} & \emph{страна}/\emph{премьер-министр} \\ \hline
\ruby{都道府県}{とどうふけん}/\ruby{知事}{ちじ} & \emph{префектура}/\emph{губернатор} \\ \hline
\ruby{市}{し}/\ruby{市長}{しちょう} & \emph{город}/\emph{мэр} \\ \hline
\ruby{町}{まち}/\ruby{町長}{ちょうちょう} & \emph{район}/\emph{глава района} \\ \hline
\ruby{村}{むら}/\ruby{村長}{そんちょう} & \emph{деревня}/\emph{староста} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

you get:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You might find the package `cals` useful:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}      
\usepackage{xeCJK}
%\setCJKmainfont{MS PMincho}
\setCJKmainfont{[MSMINCHO.TTF]}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
%\newfontfamily\russianfont{Calibri}
\newfontfamily\russianfont{[Calibri.ttf]}

\usepackage{ruby}
\renewcommand{\rubysep}{-0.1ex}

\usepackage{cals}

\begin{document}

\begin{calstable}
\colwidths{{28mm}{57mm}}
\makeatletter\cals@paddingT=2pt plus 1fill\relax % align bottom
\brow
\nullcell{ltb}
\nullcell{rtb}
\spancontent{Институт/Руководящая должность}
\erow
\brow
\cell{\ruby{国}{くに}/\ruby{首長}{しゅちょう}}
\cell{\emph{страна}/\emph{премьер-министр}}
\erow
\brow
\cell{\ruby{都道府県}{とどうふけん}/\ruby{知事}{ちじ}}
\cell{\emph{префектура}/\emph{губернатор}}
\erow
\brow
\cell{\ruby{市}{し}/\ruby{市長}{しちょう}}
\cell{\emph{город}/\emph{мэр}}
\erow
\brow
\cell{\ruby{町}{まち}/\ruby{町長}{ちょうちょう}}
\cell{\emph{район}/\emph{глава района}}
\erow
\brow
\cell{\ruby{村}{むら}/\ruby{村長}{そんちょう}}
\cell{\emph{деревня}/\emph{староста}}
\erow
\end{calstable}

\end{document}
```